# Html Helper won't take style parameters

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

To be able to navigate through pages in a grid and also viewing items' details, I needed to do a custom helper to replace the standard ActionLink. It works flawlessly but for one little thing: it doesn't take css classes like any other helper.

This is my helper code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {

        public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkUrlParam(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            MvcHtmlString link;
            RouteValueDictionary val = new RouteValueDictionary();

            if (routeValues != null)
            {
                val = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
            }

            if (helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Query != "")
            {
                string[] results = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Query.Replace("?", "").Replace("%2F", "/").Replace("%2f", "/").Split(new string[] { "&" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                if (results.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in results)
                    {
                        val.Add(item.Split(new Char[] { '=' })[0], item.Split(new Char[] { '=' })[1]);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (htmlAttributes == null)
            {
                link = Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(helper, linkText, actionName, val);
            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> html = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                html.Add("class", htmlAttributes);
                link = Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(helper, linkText, actionName, val, html);
            }

            return link;
        }
    }
}
```

In the item details view, I have the following buttons, and everyone is using the css classes fine but for the one in which I use my custom helper. This is the segment of that code:

```
    <div class="acciones">
    <div class="float-left">
        <p>
             @ViewBag.Menu @Html.ActionLink(Global.DespachoTitle, "Index") / @Html.ActionLink(Global.Details_Title, "Details_KO", new { id=Model.Id }) 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="float-right">
        <input data-bind="click: $root.displayDetails" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Detalle" />
        <input data-bind="click: $root.displayCeder" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ceder" />
        <input data-bind="click: $root.displayFacturas" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Facturas" />
        <input data-bind="click: $root.displayBoletos" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Boletos" />
        <input data-bind="click: $root.displayMSDs" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="MSD" />
        <input data-bind="click: $root.displayDevoluciones" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Devoluciones" />
        <input data-bind="click: $root.displayCertificaciones" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Certificaciones" />
        <input data-bind="click: $root.displayOtrasImputaciones" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Otras Imputaciones" />
        @Html.ActionLinkUrlParam(Global.BackToList, "Filter", null, new { type = "button", @class = "btn btn-primary active" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been changing the css classes, looking for similar cases on the web but I can't seem to find anything for this particular cases.

Please tell me if any information about this is missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the `class` attribute on the `Filter` link look like if you do a View Source?

Comment: You might want to look at this function [HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.anonymousobjecttohtmlattributes(v=vs.118).aspx)  I think the existing ActionLink helper uses this function to convert anonymous objects e.g. `new { @class = "hello" }` into a RouteValueDictionary that can then be used like any other dictionary.

Comment: Jason, I at looked the code from the View Source in the browser and it looks like this: `<a class="{ class = btn btn-primary }" href="/Despacho/Filter?FechaDesde=01%2F07%2F2015&amp;FechaHasta=01%2F07%2F2015">Volver</a>`



Looks like I'm doing the formatting wrong in the `Dictionary<string, object> html = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                html.Add("class", htmlAttributes);`

Any suggestions?

Comment: What type of object is `htmlAttributes`?  From the resultant HTML it looks ilke you might need something like `html.Add("class", htmlAttributes.@class);` instead of what you've got.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I'll try that on Monday. I really like your approach, since I wouldn't have to maintain the helper html classes in case they changed on the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jason Evans for this. His suggestion of using a function made me look into it, and in another thread there something suggested that I could use:

```
var attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
if (!enabled)
{
    attrs.Add("disabled", "disabled");
}
return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, null /* optionLabel */, attrs);
```

I added my css classes in the "attrs" variable and that was it. I'll have to remember this if the css suffers modifications, but apart from that is working.